# How to group a specific year in SQL i would only like people who were hired in 2023 to be called and have their salary sum up and average

Tags: sql, azure

```
SELECT 
SUM(monthly_salary) as total,
AVG(monthly_salary) as average
FROM employees_list
GROUP BY YEAR(hire_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to target the sum and average from a specific year, then drop the `GROUP BY` clause and add a `WHERE` filter:

```sql
SELECT SUM(monthly_salary) AS total, AVG(monthly_salary) AS average
FROM employees_list
WHERE YEAR(hire_date) = 2023;
```